# Owl Carousal Arrows are not in center

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

Owl Carousal Arrows are not in center.
How I align them to center?
Please see the attached image.

[image: See that image]

Comment: Please show your current code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```
this is how I solved the problem, I added class brand-slides to the carousal selector and using fallowing css solved the problem forme
     .brands-slides.controls-cust-clr .owl-controls .owl-prev, .brands-slides.controls-cust-clr .owl-controls .owl-next {
      font-size: 20px;
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
      background: transparent;
      color: #e0e0e0;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 35px;
      margin: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      transition: 0.3s all ease 0s;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      top: 45.5%; 
    }
      .brands-slides.controls-cust-clr .owl-controls .owl-prev:hover, .brands-slides.controls-cust-clr .owl-controls .owl-next:hover {
        color: #e0e0e0; 
        background: transparent;
      }
      .pricing-content > li{
        height: 60px;
      }
```